# How to open new view from UITableViewRow button click event?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to open the new View Controller from my first view that is Table View Controller.

[image: This is View from Simulator.]

First View Controller: TableView Controller with Rows.
Second View Controller: TableView Controller, Detail View Controller for the selected row on the First Table View Controller.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Foundation;
    using UIKit;

    namespace TourStops.iOS {

        class TourStopsTableSource : UITableViewSource {
            private List<TourLib.TourStop> _stops;
            NSString _cellID = new NSString("TableCell");
FirstViewController _fvc;
            public TourStopsTableSource(FirstViewController fvc) {
                _stops = TourLib.TourSource.GetAllTourStops();
_fvc = fvc;
            }

            public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
            {
                // tell the TableView how many rows to create
                return _stops.Count;
            }
            public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
                TourLib.TourStop currentTourStop = _stops[indexPath.Row];

                var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellID) as TourStopTableCell;
                if (cell == null) { cell = new TourStopTableCell(_cellID); }


                cell.UpdateCellControlsWithTourData(currentTourStop.Name, currentTourStop.Phone);

                #region SetupMapButton
                string mapUrl = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps?q={0}+{1}",
                                                                                    currentTourStop.Latitude,
                                                                                    currentTourStop.Longitude);
                cell.MapButton.TouchUpInside += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(mapUrl));
                }; 
                #endregion
                cell.CallButton.TouchUpInside += OpenDetailView;

                return cell;
            }

            private void OpenDetailView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                 var view = new SecondDetailController();
  _parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true);
            }

        }
    }
```

**My FirstViewController Class:**

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace TourStops.iOS
{
    public partial class FirstViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public FirstViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public FirstViewController ()
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            TourStopsTable.Source = new TourStopsTableSource(new FirstViewController ());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Exception after following the steps of Jason.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the NavigationController.  There are multiple ways to do this, but one common patter is when you create your Source, pass in a reference to it's parent VC

```
ViewController _parent;

public TourStopsTableSource(UIViewController parent) {
  _stops = TourLib.TourSource.GetAllTourStops();
  _parent = parent;
}
```

then, assuming your parent VC is contained within a NavigationController,

```
private void OpenDetailView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var view = new SomeDetailController();
  _parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(view, true);
}
```

Edit:

In your amended example above, you are doing

```
TourStopsTable.Source = new TourStopsTableSource(new FirstViewController ());
```

instead you need to pass a reference to the ALREADY EXISTING VC:

```
TourStopsTable.Source = new TourStopsTableSource(this);
```

Comment: But this didn't worked for me.

I did it the same way you said, but it give the exception, details of exception are below:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

  at Navigation.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/Admin/Projects/TourStops/TourStops/Main.cs:12


I am updating my question with steps you told me.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you please provide a working example if you have any!.

Comment: Thank you.
It worked.
How can i pass values from my first View to second View? I need to pass multiple values on the RowClick Event.

Comment: pass them as parameters to the constructor of the 2nd view

Comment: My Next View is coming on clicking the button, but its simple black. Nothing which i put over the view is coming. (This is with and without passing parameters).

Comment: I did it in this way and it worked, now my next view has data. :-) Thanks for your help @Jason.

var view = _parent.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondDetailController") as SecondDetailController;